# How setState based on previous value of state is executed asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've read that setState is async so I think setState based on previous value of state is also async. No I wonder how multiple setState calls in a row are executed perfectly true. Consider this code:

```
const IncrementByFive = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      setNum(prevNum => prevNum + 1);
    }
  };
```

If setNum is async, then they may have race condition so the final value wouldn't be true (my thoughts). How this feature is implemented?

Comment: I think this article should answer your questions - https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/state-as-a-snapshot

Comment: Those calls to setState will be stacked in that order. No race condition.